# FreeMarker is not setting the pages that use the include tag twith UTF-8 encoding

Tags: html, spring-mvc, utf-8, freemarker, template-engine

I created a Master PAge using freemarker tag `macro` like this

```
<#macro masterPageLay>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Myapp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <#include "sectionMasterPage/head.html"/>
</head>

<body ng-cloack>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <#include "sectionMasterPage/menu.html"/>

        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <!--   here goes the content-->
            <#nested>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
    <#include "sectionMasterPage/scriptsFooter.html"/>
</body>
</html>
</#macro>
```

My head partial

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>SuprBT Administrador de actividades</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="/AdministradorActividades/resources/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
<link href="/AdministradorActividades/resources/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

.....more css
```

A page that don't use the master page and the UTF-8 works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="SistemaActividades">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <#include "sectionMasterPage/head.html"/>
</head>

<body ng-cloack>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Navigation -->
```

The page use the master page and don't work

```
<#import "../masterPage.html" as layout>
<@layout.masterPageLay>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">User Profile</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
<div class="row" ng-cloack>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">

        ... html more tags

</@layout.masterPageLay>
```

Why is the UTF-8 working in the pages that don't use the master page and the ones that use it doesn't work the UTF-8.

The pages that use the page the UTF-8 doesn't work but the css and all the things that I include in the head works

Comment: In what sense doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see if the actual files themselves are saved with UTF-8 encoding? That can affect the output.